# Set value in a column on click of a button in SharePoint

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I have a customized form in SharePoint 2013. I want that on click of the submit button on the list, a value will also update.

Currently on click of the submit button, it is saving the values and redirecting to the home page.

```
<input type="button" value="Submit" name="btnFormAction" onclick="javascript: {ddwrt:GenFireServerEvent('__commit;__redirect={https://homepage.aspx}')}" style="width: 119px" />
```

I have created one flag with default value as 0, I want once the user click on the submit button this flag value will change to 1.

Comment: Have you tried an event receiver on that list, which updates the column, or do you need a javascript solution?

Comment: I am looking for the JavaScript solution...